# Handling calender to select to date from the current date in the calender? Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I'm working in MakeMyTrip site for handling the calender. After selecting the from date i want to select to date after 7 or 8 days from the selected from date..

Link: https://www.makemytrip.com/

I'm able to select the current date, using the class name which has today

I don't know how to handle selecting the to date like after n number of days after from date

HTML code:
[image]

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH,using = "//div[@class = 'DayPicker-Month'][1]//div[@class='DayPicker-Body']//div[contains(@class,'DayPicker-Day')]")
List<WebElement> DepartureDateList;

//Selecting Departure Date
public void selectDepartureDate() {

    for ( WebElement date : DepartureDateList) {

        if (date.getAttribute("class").contains("--today")) {

            date.click();
            break;

        }
```

Comment: Which date do you want to select/choose?

Comment: Want to select 7 days after current date !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple solution.

First get the nth day using the below code.

```
    int numberOfDays = 7;
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, numberOfDays);
    String toDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(toDate);
```

Then select the data in the calendar using the below xpath.

```
String toDateXpath = "//div[@class='DayPicker-Day' and contains(@aria-label,'" + toDate + "')]"
driver.findElement(By.xpath(toDateXpath)).click();
```